# How to rescale dataframe values to 0 and 1?

Tags: r

I want to rescale my dataframe `protein` to between 0 and 1.

```
protein <- as.numeric(unlist(protein))    
protein <- apply(protein, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(X) (X - min(X))/diff(range(X)))
```

Traceback:

```
Error in apply(protein, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(X) (X - min(X))/diff(range(X))) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

Data:

```
> dput(protein[1:10,1:10])
structure(list(TCGA.A3.3357.01 = c("0.43216667125", "0.27655395325", 
"-0.05052052725", "-0.13792455525", "0.07409333175", "-0.47918122425", 
"-0.0175397277500001", "-0.31555082025", "0.17598078475", "-0.32440180325"
), TCGA.A3.3367.01 = c("0.22529132975", "-0.12950190925", "0.00483883425000009", 
"0.13180277925", "-0.09403284175", "-0.32915906875", "0.16454402775", 
"0.0673332472499999", "0.0282689282499999", "-0.57593626275"), 
    TCGA.A3.3387.01 = c("0.0428932150000005", "0.0548635820000001", 
    "0.0339660955000001", "-0.0440775865", "-0.2434882025", "-0.1171357375", 
    "-0.500200476", "0.4330998585", "-0.0195380545000001", "0.0573784155"
    ), TCGA.B0.4698.01 = c("0.502301219", "0.327746334", "2.5017964265", 
    "0.8452782975", "0.0452485464999999", "0.6489117815", "0.610451403", 
    "-0.5377816785", "0.3412347885", "1.1108757225"), TCGA.B0.4710.01 = c("0.342431330750001", 
    "0.33447894175", "0.30921895025", "0.29504738925", "-0.26837205975", 
    "0.90950231825", "-0.67599687525", "-0.34704194275", "0.12366059425", 
    "0.0922109122500001"), TCGA.B0.4810.01 = c("-0.1528553115", 
    "-0.0890113614999999", "0.110224878", "0.531443884", "0.705128991", 
    "1.576618035", "0.6941767135", "-0.013302181", "-0.203134214", 
    "0.528934355"), TCGA.B0.4811.01 = c("0.0564247582500002", 
    "-0.0312831207499999", "-0.11710900625", "-0.00937909725000008", 
    "0.10141934375", "0.63522999475", "-0.11573650675", "0.36754486275", 
    "-0.10905751725", "0.51649620875"), TCGA.B0.4815.01 = c("0.0711154310000005", 
    "-0.0181620079999999", "-0.00635163549999995", "-0.2597877095", 
    "-0.0626275074999999", "0.1845338715", "0.117613381", "0.2185215415", 
    "-0.4099665705", "0.1484769175"), TCGA.B0.4818.01 = c("-0.0697927272499997", 
    "0.12253850775", "0.39577983525", "0.40226443825", "0.0962845262499997", 
    "0.46560829625", "0.29552204975", "-0.23290107475", "0.29492263125", 
    "0.27064606525"), TCGA.B0.4821.01 = c("0.13600020325", "0.15874590925", 
    "0.47381080675", "0.0716422437499998", "-0.29596241525", 
    "0.23818164575", "0.17422681825", "-0.52034638725", "0.60918152875", 
    "-0.17272622525")), row.names = c("14-3-3_beta", "14-3-3_epsilon", 
"14-3-3_zeta", "4E-BP1", "4E-BP1_pS65", "4E-BP1_pT37_T46", "4E-BP1_pT70", 
"53BP1", "A-Raf_pS299", "ACC1"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You should convert your data to numeric using `as.numeric`?

Comment: As Quinten pointed out, your data.frame contains values stored as strings: `"0.63522999475"` is not the same as `0.63522999475`. Therefore your function fails.

Comment: I posted the wrong code and traceback. I did convert it to numeric and it raised `dim(X) must have a positive length`

Comment: @melolili I think the error is because of reassignment of your object to a vector `protein <- as.numeric(unlist(protein))`.  Try the code on a fresh R session i.e. `library(dplyr);type.convert(protein, as.is = TRUE) %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ (.x -min(.x))/diff(range(.x))))`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your original `protein` data, you could use

```r
apply(protein, 2, \(x) {
  x <- as.numeric(x) 
  (x - min(x)) / diff(range(x))
})
```

Using `unlist()` like shown in your first code block, doesn't make any sense (at least for me), since it changes the data.frame into a vector.

##### Output

On my machine this returns:

```r
#> apply(protein, 2, \(x) {
#+   x <- as.numeric(x) 
#+   (x - min(x)) / diff(range(x))
#+ })
      TCGA.A3.3357.01 TCGA.A3.3367.01 TCGA.A3.3387.01 TCGA.B0.4698.01 TCGA.B0.4710.01 TCGA.B0.4810.01 TCGA.B0.4811.01
 [1,]       1.0000000       1.0000000       0.5819067       0.3421800       0.6423392      0.02825051      0.23065900
 [2,]       0.8292499       0.5571879       0.5947325       0.2847527       0.6373235      0.06412289      0.11407874
 [3,]       0.4703590       0.7248566       0.5723416       1.0000000       0.6213916      0.17606894      0.00000000
 [4,]       0.3744527       0.8833184       0.4887204       0.4550171       0.6124533      0.41274177      0.14319331
 [5,]       0.6070948       0.6014563       0.2750586       0.1918129       0.2570956      0.51033126      0.29046527
 [6,]       0.0000000       0.3079989       0.4104410       0.3904139       1.0000000      1.00000000      1.00000000
 [7,]       0.5065480       0.9241822       0.0000000       0.3777607       0.0000000      0.50417744      0.00182431
 [8,]       0.1795477       0.8028549       1.0000000       0.0000000       0.2074772      0.10666206      0.64419612
 [9,]       0.7188934       0.7540993       0.5150137       0.2891903       0.5043569      0.00000000      0.01070194
[10,]       0.1698357       0.0000000       0.5974271       0.5423968       0.4845211      0.41133173      0.84218047
      TCGA.B0.4815.01 TCGA.B0.4818.01 TCGA.B0.4821.01
 [1,]       0.7654592       0.2335092       0.5810805
 [2,]       0.6234081       0.5088544       0.6012178
 [3,]       0.6421998       0.9000322       0.8801528
 [4,]       0.2389526       0.9093157       0.5241027
 [5,]       0.5526581       0.4712687       0.1986529
 [6,]       0.9459215       1.0000000       0.6715443
 [7,]       0.8394430       0.7565011       0.6149235
 [8,]       1.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000
 [9,]       0.0000000       0.7556430       1.0000000
[10,]       0.8885506       0.7208882       0.3077570
```

Comment: It raised `Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : attempt to apply non-function`

Comment: What R Version are you using? Try changing `\(x)` to `function(x)`.

Comment: Still the same error. I'm using R 4.2.2

Comment: Did you use your `dput(protein[1:10,1:10])` shown in your question as `protein` data here?

Comment: Yes I used the dput

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce your error. See code and output above.